# What file formats does HDHomeRun DVR's app scan/monitor?

Tags: video, video-conversion, recording

Title is the question. I'm using file conversion software, MCEBuddy to trim  video files, mpg - HDHomeRun Unprocessed, and would prefer to convert the file to a format more widely adopted, ideally supported and optimal for [Plex](https://support.plex.tv/hc/en-us/articles/203810286-What-media-formats-are-supported-). My initial thought was mp4, however the files don't seems to show up on the front end, HDHomeRuns app. The support docs or [forum](https://forum.silicondust.com/forum/search.php?&sr=topics&search_id=newposts) don't seem to detail this.

Answer (score 0):

After testing a few formats it seems their app searches for only hdhomerun format (mpg). Their support confirmed this, and they place metadata in the first part of the file. skipping trim in the first five minutes part of processing to remove commercials works on my end.